# Querying an array with objects inside

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently having trouble querying my database. My goal is to find a conversation that contains both users' unique IDs. This is a sample of what the data I'm trying to query looks like:

```
{
   _id: 6032cfdbe52ce0cc3262462f,
   participants: [
     {
       _id: 6032cfdbe52ce0cc32624630,
       participant: 60224ac272aa3a1921048495
     },
     {
       _id: 6032cfdbe52ce0cc32624631,
       participant: 601e05cf49770d0246b90d02
     }
   ],
   __v: 0
 }
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
// Checking to see if conversation already exists
    const conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
        // Saving Sender and Recipient's ID
        "participants.participant": req.user._id,
        "participants.participant": recipient._id
});
```

Unfortunately, this only finds any conversation that matches any of these ids instead of exclusive finding a conversation between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it must have both the elements but could have others then currently you need to use an [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) expression:

```
// Checking to see if conversation already exists
const conversation = await Conversation.findOne({
  // Saving Sender and Recipient's ID
  $and: [
    { "participants.participant": req.user._id },
    { "participants.participant": recipient._id }
  ]
});
```